# Separate Blurred image using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing

I have two images which are quite similar but one of them is a little bit blurred. In image processing, is there any parameter or way to detect the blurred image and separate it from the other one?

Comment: What type of blur is it?

Comment: It has lower quality (It is a little bit more blurred).

Comment: Could you put a link to the pictures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if an image is blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864995/determine-if-an-image-is-blurred)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways to find a blurred image is by using Laplacian operator.

Steps:

1) Read image1 and image2 and convert them to grayscale

2) Use Laplacian operator to get the edge image.

3) Find the variance of the Laplacian image.

4) Compare the variances of image1 and image2.

5) The image which has the least variance is blurred.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry#7766036) link for additional information